# Google Drive SDK, can it do this?

Tags: google-drive-api

StackOverFlowers:

I not if this is possible, so I wanted to ask quickly.

Can I:

1. Create a Document and Share it with other Google Users (using the Google API's)
2. Update that document when needed.. mostly add content to a spreadsheet.

3.. if 1&2 are possible, what libraries do I use for this.. I'm looking at the
Javascript APIs now, and I have used the PHP libraries in the past.

Any guidance is helpful..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are possible using the Drive SDK. Updating the the file might be tricky, because you have to download it, update it locally then re-upload it, but that is not hard when using something like CSV.

For Javascript, please check out the [Google Drive SDK Javascript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-js).